# How to setup tradingview alert with specific decimals?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to set up alerts in tradingview when my condition is met.

Hoewer my problem is that I get only 2 numbers after a comma and I need 3 of them.

I've tried a couple of things, but I cannot figure it out to work properly.

```
strategy(title="ScalpSMA30",shorttitle="ScalpSMA30",precision=3,overlay=true, calc_on_every_tick=true)

condition_long = close[1]>open[1] and close[0]>open[0] and crossover(close[1],sma1) and high[0]>=point
condition_short = crossunder(close[1],sma1) and close[1]<open[1] and low[0]<open[0] and low[0]<=point1 

strategy.entry("Long Condition", strategy.long, 100, when=condition_long) 
strategy.entry("Short Condition", strategy.short, 100, when=condition_short) 

// Declaring alerts

if condition_long
    alert("Go long (Entry is " + tostring(close, "#.###)"), alert.freq_once_per_bar)
if condition_short
    alert("Go short (Entry is " + tostring(close, "#.###)"), alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to set correct precision for the strategy properties (precision = 3):

```
strategy(title="ScalpSMA30",shorttitle="ScalpSMA30", precision = 3, overlay=true, calc_on_every_tick=true)
```

2. When `precision` parameter is set to `2`, then `#.###` modifier of `tostring()` will not return `close` value with more than 2 digits.
   Also, if current chart symbol `close` value is big and `tick size` of is only 2 decimal values, you will not get 3rd value when tostringing that number.

So:

```
strategy(title="ScalpSMA30",shorttitle="ScalpSMA30",precision=3,overlay=true, calc_on_every_tick=true)

/// ....


if condition_long
    alert("Go long (Entry is " + tostring(close), alert.freq_once_per_bar)
if condition_short
    alert("Go short (Entry is " + tostring(close), alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

Or

```
strategy(title="ScalpSMA30",shorttitle="ScalpSMA30",precision=3,overlay=true, calc_on_every_tick=true)

/// ....


if condition_long
    alert("Go long (Entry is " + tostring(close, '#.###'), alert.freq_once_per_bar)
if condition_short
    alert("Go short (Entry is " + tostring(close, '#.###'), alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

is what you need.

Comment: Thank you, your second answer works like I wanted to :)
It seems like I messed up signs, because I've had precision 3 before.